# Plot many different lines; base legend on column A (visibility); base color on column B

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to visualize certain data in an HTML file using R.
Environment:

- R: version 4.2.2
- R Studio: version 2022.07.2+576
- libraries: tidyverse, plotly

I have 100 CSV-Files named `00_Trace, ... , 99_Trace`. Each file has three columns (time, Cylinder_0, Cylinder_1) and 500 data points plus one 1 title lines. The lines represent the trace of two positions over time.

Importing the CSV-Files leads to data of the following form:

```
time       filename              Cylinder_0  Cylinder_1
...
979.971    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.9        9.0    
981.967    00_Trace_Retract.csv   2.0        5.0    
984.062    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.7        9.0    
985.964    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.7        1.0    
987.995    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.3        1.0    
989.978    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.6        9.0    
991.973    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.6        1.0    
994.091    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.6        1.0    
995.960    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.7        1.1    
997.986    00_Trace_Retract.csv   1.7        1.0
...
```

I can mutate the values to numeric, pivot_longer the data set to one value and additional column for Position_A or Position_B.

What I want is basically to have a legend in order to choose which file(s) (00_Trace ... 99_Trace) shall be shown; always two traces. The color of the line should be based on Position_A (blue) and Position_B (grey).

I tried:

```
data <- readAllCsvData("data") %>% 
  rename(time = `time..s.`) %>% 
  select(-X) %>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>% 
  mutate(Cylinder_0 = as.numeric(Cylinder_0)) %>% 
  mutate(Cylinder_1 = as.numeric(Cylinder_1)) %>% 
  mutate(Dev_new = Cylinder_0 - Cylinder_1) %>% 
  mutate(Deviation = as.numeric(Deviation)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Cylinder_0, Cylinder_1), names_to = "Cylinder")

gg <- data %>% 
  filter(grepl(".*Advance.*", filename)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value, group = filename, color = Cylinder)) 

ggplotly(gg)
```

But I only get the following. Colors are basically alright, just need to change the actually used color. But I can only select
Cylinder_0 or Cylinder_1, not for example 50_Trace.

[image]

Can this be solved in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I tried several different ways where the plot was initiated as a `ggplot` object, but couldn't get any of them to work.

However, I did come up with a few different methods that work in Plotly without starting in `ggplot`.

This answer really shows one method of making this happen in Plotly and a few methods to customize it further. This uses buttons. I did come up with a method that would allow you to have something like a legend to click on to change files, but it was ugly and not something that would be all that easy to implement.

##### Creating the Buttons

By use of buttons, you can have individual buttons for each file. Alternatively, you can have a drop-down menu to choose the file-- which may be better if you have 99 files.

First, here's a function that will create a single button, considering how you've set your data up.

```
btn <- function(lab, x, y){   # lab: (string) button label
  # x: (int) number of traces; y: (vector) traces to make visible
  v = rep(F, x)  
  v[y] = T
  list(method = "restyle",          # make the button
       label = lab,
       args = list(list(visible = unlist(v))))
}
```

To use this `btn` function, we need a list of unique file names and something that will call this function to create a list of buttons—one for each file name.

```
filenames <- unique(dta$filename) # unique files

btns <- lapply(                   # create button for each file name
  1:length(filenames),
  function(j) {
    btn(filenames[j], 
        length(filenames)*2,         # 2 <-- 1 for each color
        c(j, j + length(filenames))) # <- all blue traces created first
  }
)
```

##### Using the Buttons; Creating the Plot

Now all that's left to do is create the plot. This plot version uses individual buttons (not a dropdown). I only used 3 'files' in my sample data since your question isn't reproducible.

```
plot_ly(dta2, x = ~time, y = ~value, split = ~filename, color = ~Cylinder,
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
        colors = ~c("Cylinder_0" = "blue", "Cylinder_1" = "grey")) %>% 
  layout(updatemenus = list(
    list(type = "buttons", buttons = btns)   # <--- type changed!
  ))
```

[image]

This plot uses a dropdown menu instead.

[image]

##### Updating the Legend Names

I thought that the 'cylinder...file' in the legend was ugly and rather cumbersome, so I also came up with a workaround to rid yourself of that, too.

```
fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data),
         function(k) {
           plt$x$data[[k]]$name <<- str_extract(plt$x$data[[k]]$name,
                                                "^.*(?=\\<)")
         })
  plt
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
plot_ly(dta2, x = ~time, y = ~value, split = ~filename, color = ~Cylinder,
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
        colors = ~c("Cylinder_0" = "blue", "Cylinder_1" = "grey")) %>% 
  layout(updatemenus = list(
    list(type = "dropdown", buttons = btns)
  )) %>% fixer()                               # <-- I'm new!
```

[image]

##### All the Code in One Chunk

Since there are a lot of separate chunks of code, here's all the code you need to create a drop-down menu and updated legend names version altogether.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

btn <- function(lab, x, y){   # lab: (string) button label
  # x: (int) number of traces; y: (vector) traces to make visible
  v = rep(F, x)  
  v[y] = T
  list(method = "restyle",          # make the button
       label = lab,
       args = list(list(visible = unlist(v))))
}

filenames <- unique(dta$filename)

btns <- lapply(                   # create button for each file name
  1:length(filenames),
  function(j) {
    btn(filenames[j], 
        length(filenames)*2,         # 2 <-- 1 for each color
        c(j, j + length(filenames))) # <- all blue traces created first
  }
)

fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data),
         function(k) {
           plt$x$data[[k]]$name <<- str_extract(plt$x$data[[k]]$name,
                                                "^.*(?=\\<)")
         })
  plt
}

plot_ly(dta2, x = ~time, y = ~value, split = ~filename, color = ~Cylinder,
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
        colors = ~c("Cylinder_0" = "blue", "Cylinder_1" = "grey")) %>% 
  layout(updatemenus = list(
    list(type = "dropdown", buttons = btns)
  )) %>% fixer()
```